# "nawk if else if else" not working

Tags: nawk

ok, this is most probably going to sound like a stupid question to you, but I can't make it work and really don't know what I do wrong here even after reading quite a few nawk/awk help sites:

```
    $ echo -e "hey\nthis\nworld" | nawk '{ if ( $1 !~ /e/ ) { print $0; } else if ($1 !~ /o/ ) { print $0; } else { print "condition not mached"; } }'
    hey
    this
    world
    $
```

I'd prefer to have it on one line but also tried on multiple lines as seen in various examples:

```
    $ echo -e "hey\nthis\nworld" | nawk '{ 
    if ( $1 !~ /e/ )
    print $0;
    else if ($1 !~ /o/ )
    print $0;
    else
    print "condition not matched"
    }'
    hey
    this
    world
    $
```

Thanks in advance for helping a nawk-newbie!

I simply want to have only printed lines not containing a certain pattern, here "e" or "o".
The final else I only added for testing-purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your life a lot easier by simply doing:

```
echo "hey\nthis\nworld" | nawk '$1 !~ /e|o/'
```

What is going wrong in your case is:

```
$ echo -e "hey\nthis\nworld" | nawk '{ 
if ( $1 !~ /e/ ) #'this' and 'world' satisfy this condition and so are printed 
print $0; 
else if ($1 !~ /o/ ) #Only 'hey' falls through to this test and passes and prints
print $0;
else
print "condition not matched"
}'
hey
this
world
$
```

Comment: thank you Ell!
now I see my misunderstanding in the if-construct.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the right way to do this is with a character list inside a ternary expression:

```
awk '{ print ($1 ~ /[eo]/ ? $0 : "condition not matched") }'
```

Going forward if you tag your questions with `awk` instead of just `nawk` (which is an old, non-POSIX and relatively redundant awk variant) they'll reach a much wider audience.